# Why i am getting "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'' when my training data is large?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

My hardware is Intel Pentium , 8 GB RAM ,250 GB Hard Disk  without GPU .I am able to train data with 400 images but when i increase number of images to 1000 it is throwing error

```
<pre>2019-10-31 21:55:05.844961: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2
terminate called after throwing an instance of &apos;std::bad_alloc&apos;
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
</pre>
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error implies that your running out memory.

**special considerations:**

In some instances, it could be caused by memory fragmentation in that you actually have enough memory to service your task but because it's not contiguous, it can't be used.

OR

a process is allocated a large memory portion that some is left unoccupied and cannot be used by another process.

Running `tf.reset_default_graph()` between training may help to free up memory in-case fragmentation is the real issue.
The `keras.clear_session()` method is an alternative to `tf.reset_default_graph()` that may help free memory in-case of fragmentation.